# What is Use of app:met_floatingLabel="normal XML element

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I was just trying out a library for using material design components and found a sample here [link](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-material-design-spinner-dropdown-example.html).

And the layout xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="demos.com.demos.MainActivity">

    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/android_material_design_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Material Design Spinner"
        android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is what is use of app namespace and specifically what is `app:met_floatingLabel="normal` used for?

Comment: As far as it seems to me, this causes the text to be in highlighted, normal or custom color. The parameter must be a color code, it also can be set programmatically with `setFloatingLabel(int color)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `app` indicates that is not from android, is from the app (including libraries that the app uses.
- in specific `met_floatingLabel` you have to check the documentation of the library. That is a parameter created by the developer of that library.